# Create New Categorical Variable (high, mid, low)

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data

I have this dataframe, and I would like to create a new categorical variable ‘life.cat’ that denotes for each country in each year, whether it is ‘High’ (> = 1 SD above the mean); ‘Low’ ( < = 1 SD below the mean); or else ‘Mid’, based on its lifeExp compared to that of other countries in its continent in each year.

```
structure(list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria"), continent = c("Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa"
), year = c(1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 
1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 
1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 
1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L), lifeExp = c(28.801, 30.332, 
31.997, 34.02, 36.088, 38.438, 39.854, 40.822, 41.674, 41.763, 
42.129, 43.828, 55.23, 59.28, 64.82, 66.22, 67.69, 68.93, 70.42, 
72, 71.581, 72.95, 75.651, 76.423, 43.077, 45.685, 48.303, 51.407, 
54.518, 58.014), pop = c(8425333L, 9240934L, 10267083L, 11537966L, 
13079460L, 14880372L, 12881816L, 13867957L, 16317921L, 22227415L, 
25268405L, 31889923L, 1282697L, 1476505L, 1728137L, 1984060L, 
2263554L, 2509048L, 2780097L, 3075321L, 3326498L, 3428038L, 3508512L, 
3600523L, 9279525L, 10270856L, 11000948L, 12760499L, 14760787L, 
17152804L), gdpPercap = c(779.4453145, 820.8530296, 853.10071, 
836.1971382, 739.9811058, 786.11336, 978.0114388, 852.3959448, 
649.3413952, 635.341351, 726.7340548, 974.5803384, 1601.056136, 
1942.284244, 2312.888958, 2760.196931, 3313.422188, 3533.00391, 
3630.880722, 3738.932735, 2497.437901, 3193.054604, 4604.211737, 
5937.029526, 2449.008185, 3013.976023, 2550.81688, 3246.991771, 
4182.663766, 4910.416756)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

So far, I have tried this code:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(continent, year) %>% 
    mutate(Mean = mean(lifeExp), 
           SD = sd(lifeExp),
           life.cat = case_when(Mean > (Mean + SD) ~ 'High',     
                                Mean < (Mean - SD) ~ 'Low', 
          TRUE ~ 'Mid'  ), Mean = NULL, SD = NULL) %>%
    ungroup
```

But the output in the new column is all "mid", which is not possible. Could any one tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Each continent-year only has one value in the subset of data you shared here, since Afghanistan, Albania, and Algeria are on different continents. SD produces an NA running on that example data since each group only has one element. It should work ok if there are multiple elements in each group. The NA in SD means that the case_when's first two terms will be false (in R, no number is bigger or smaller than NA), hence all "mid".

If you can't know there will be multiple elements in each group ahead of time, you might change `sd(lifeExp)` to `coalesce(sd(lifeExp, 0)` so that any NA's for SD turn into zeroes.

You also probably want to change the code here so that the current row's `lifeExp` is compared to the `Mean+SD` for its group. Comparing `Mean > Mean + SD` is always false, and `Mean < Mean - SD` is also always false.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `within` and `ave` and do a straightforward case handling using bracketing. (Your data is not suitable for demonstration, I have created them new.)

```
e <- within(e, {
    le.mn <- ave(lifeExp, continent, year, FUN=mean)
    le.sd <- ave(lifeExp, continent, FUN=sd)
    life.cat <- NA
    life.cat[lifeExp < le.mn - le.sd] <- "lo"
    life.cat[lifeExp >= le.mn - le.sd] <- "mid"
    life.cat[lifeExp > le.mn + le.sd] <- "hi"
    rm(le.mn, le.sd)
})
e
#    country year continent  lifeExp life.cat
# 1        a 2015         A 29.14806      mid
# 2        a 2016         A 29.37075       hi
# 3        a 2017         A 22.86140      mid
# 4        a 2018         A 28.30448      mid
# 5        a 2019         A 26.41746      mid
# 6        a 2020         A 25.19096      mid
# 7        b 2015         A 27.36588      mid
# 8        b 2016         A 21.34667       lo
# 9        b 2017         A 26.56992      mid
# 10       b 2018         A 27.05065      mid
# 11       b 2019         A 24.57742      mid
# 12       b 2020         A 27.19112      mid
# 13       c 2015         B 29.34672      mid
# 14       c 2016         B 22.55429      mid
# 15       c 2017         B 24.62293      mid
# 16       c 2018         B 29.40015       hi
# 17       c 2019         B 29.78226      mid
# 18       c 2020         B 21.17487       lo
# 19       d 2015         B 24.74997      mid
# 20       d 2016         B 25.60333      mid
# 21       d 2017         B 29.04031      mid
# 22       d 2018         B 21.38710       lo
# 23       d 2019         B 29.88892      mid
# 24       d 2020         B 29.46668       hi
```

---

*Data:*

```
e <- structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), year = c(2015L,
2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L,
2019L, 2020L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2015L,
2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L), continent = c("A", "A", "A",
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B",
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), lifeExp = c(29.1480604349636,
29.3707541329786, 22.8613953478634, 28.3044762606733, 26.41745518893,
25.1909594913013, 27.3658831464127, 21.3466659723781, 26.5699229040183,
27.0506478403695, 24.5774177624844, 27.191122516524, 29.3467224715278,
22.5542882434092, 24.6229282254353, 29.4001452275552, 29.7822642838582,
21.1748736165464, 24.7499708156101, 25.6033274624497, 29.0403138729744,
21.3871016772464, 29.8889172892086, 29.466682325583)), out.attrs = list(
    dim = c(country = 4L, year = 6L), dimnames = list(country = c("country=a",
    "country=b", "country=c", "country=d"), year = c("year=2015",
    "year=2016", "year=2017", "year=2018", "year=2019", "year=2020"
    ))), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```